# Trouble understanding this CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm absolutely new to C++/CMake and from all the tutorials I've read, there should be an `add_executable()` line in the top-level CMakeLists.txt file. However, in this project that I'm working on, there isn't one:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(VERSION dev)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM $ENV{HOME}/usr/local/include)

project(engine)
add_subdirectory(common)

add_subdirectory(matching)
add_subdirectory(matching_test)
add_subdirectory(matching_tcp_client)
add_subdirectory(matching_tcp_service)
add_subdirectory(md_tcp_service)

add_subdirectory(matching_zmq_service)

add_subdirectory(net)

add_subdirectory(proxy_ws)
add_subdirectory(proxy_md_ws)
add_subdirectory(zmq_proxy)

add_subdirectory(test_tcp_matching_client)
add_subdirectory(test_tcp_matching_server)
add_subdirectory(test_md_tcp_server)

add_subdirectory(test_zmq_matching_server)
add_subdirectory(xpubxsub)

add_subdirectory(md)
```

A few questions I have:

- If there is not executable, how do I run the program?
- How can I tell where the entry point is for this program? I tried searching for a `main()` function in the entire project but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there should be an add_executable() line in the top-level CMakeLists.txt file

This is a wrong assumption.
`add_executable` is not mandatory at all.
For example, a project that produces only library will have `add_library` and no `add_executable`.
Moreover this function could be in a subdirectory, there is no need to put it in the top level `CMakeLists.txt`.

In your example, there are lost of `add_subdirectory` with a folder name as argument. Those folder should contain a `CMakeLists.txt` file.
You should look at them for a `add_executable` command. There might be several: one project could produce several executable. A common use case is a project that produce one main executable and several test executables.

Only executable needs to have a `main()` function and only one. If your project doesn't produce any executable, then there is no need to define a `main()` function.